# Google Map tutorial not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am following tutorial **["Adding a Google Map to your website"](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map)**

But for some reason its not working... may be i missed something..

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/DVT7B/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map_canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

**Note:** In the fiddle resources i have added **[Google-Api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false)**

I just cant figure-out what did i do wrong... html, css & java script all are the same as in the tutorial.. i even added `$(function (){` to make sure script loads after document but didn't helped...

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVT7B/1/).  `$(function () {}` and `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',...)` do the same thing, just call initialize inside the jquery $ function.  Adding the background-color to the css also is a problem.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip why dont you post this as an answer so that others can see and i can accept -- plus since i have to change the script, does it means google tutorial code is wrong? should we inform them?

Comment: The tutorial [works as is](http://jsfiddle.net/DVT7B/2/).  Your changes were the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is all fine.

In fiddle:
On the left top side

Below  **Frameworks and Extension**

Select:

```
No-Wrap in <head>
```

from the second drop down.

[image]

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/DVT7B/3/

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it what is frameworks & extensions? -- plus your fiddle isn't working.

Comment: Thanks! now i understand... @geocodezip solved it first.. but you have my up-vote :)

Comment: Actually your answer makes more sense - and have proper explanation on how to actually make it work...

Answer (score 1):

$(function () {} and google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',...) do the same thing, just call initialize inside the jquery $ function. Adding the background-color to the css also is a problem.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVT7B/1/)

adjusted javascript:

```
$(function () {
    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    }
    initialize();
});
```

adjusted css:

```
#map_canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```